# D3.js simple dashboard example - How can I edit display table

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using simple dashboard example from D3js
http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/96447623ef4d342ee09b

Graph display as follows (I want this table to show as I have shown at the end) :

```
low  21,027 46%
mid  14,830 33%
high 9,364  21%
```

I am using the same data set as within the script, that is -

```
<script>
var freqData=[
{State:'AL',freq:{low:4786, mid:1319, high:249}}
,{State:'AZ',freq:{low:1101, mid:412, high:674}}
,{State:'CT',freq:{low:932, mid:2149, high:418}}
,{State:'DE',freq:{low:832, mid:1152, high:1862}}
,{State:'FL',freq:{low:4481, mid:3304, high:948}}
,{State:'GA',freq:{low:1619, mid:167, high:1063}}
,{State:'IA',freq:{low:1819, mid:247, high:1203}}
,{State:'IL',freq:{low:4498, mid:3852, high:942}}
,{State:'IN',freq:{low:797, mid:1849, high:1534}}
,{State:'KS',freq:{low:162, mid:379, high:471}}
];
```

How can I display as follows:

```
State   Low     mid    high
AL      4786    1319   249
AZ      1101    412    674
..

KS      162     379    471
```

Thanks.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the `legend` function with the following code below will get you the rows you want (with no formatting, headers, etc.).  Hopefully this is enough to get you started.  Also note that you'll have to pass in `freqData`, not `tF` to the `legend` function to get this table to render with the bare minimum.  Finally, note that this doesn't tie with the pie chart and the histogram.  See the JSFiddle here for the bare minimum: https://jsfiddle.net/5v6ob9uf/

```
// function to handle legend.
function legend(lD){
    var leg = {};

    // create table for legend.
    var legend = d3.select(id).append("table").attr('class','legend');

    // create one row per segment.
    var tr = legend.append("tbody").selectAll("tr").data(lD).enter().append("tr");
    tr.append("td").text(function(d){return d.State});
    tr.append("td").text(function(d){return d.freq.low});
    tr.append("td").text(function(d){return d.freq.mid});
    tr.append("td").text(function(d){return d.freq.high});        

    return leg;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. It helped me to understand how these codes are working.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to understand how codes are working and which data to pass. But unfortunately I still couldn't add the table with the pie chart and the histogram  working. I can pass leg= legend(tF,freqData) two data variables. I think if I can read from two variables and write with legend will solve my issue. Thanks you again.